# Two for loops Linux with two input files

Tags: linux, for-loop

I have 20 files in one input and 20 files in another input. I wish to execute my command that will take two files from each input simultaneously and perform the command i.e. for each file in one input it will take the corresponding file from second input. Here is my attempt:

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc
do
  for f2 in avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-*.nc
  do
    cdo ydayadd "$f1" "$f2" ydayadd-$file
  done
done
```

I am writing the one line code that I wish will work in this loop. The syntax of code is

```
cdo ydayadd input_1 input_2 output
```

This code is running fine using one command at a time.

```
cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-ACCESS.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS.nc ydayadd-ACCESS.nc 
cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-bcc.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-bcc.nc ydayadd-bcc.nc
cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-BNU.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-BNU.nc ydayadd-BNU.nc
```

I wish to run this pattern in loop

Comment: Change the `command` to `echo "$f1" "$f2" and tell us more specifically what's wrong with it.  The way the command/script is written it will not "perform the command for each file in one input it will take the corresponding file form the second input".  What it will do is that for each file on the first input it will run the command once for each file in the second input. In other words if there are 20 files in each list, it'll run the command a total of 400 times - not 20 times.  Which behavior do you want/expect?

Comment: Yes. What is a corresponding file? You have to verbalize it clearly (which is often too hard for many programmers) or give enough examples, such that we can derive the pattern ourselves.

Comment: I wish to execute it 20 times only. My output will be just 20 files

Comment: What's *command* supposed to be. Also please elaborate on what you mean by *corresponding* file? Give example of relationship.

Comment: cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-ACCESS.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS.nc ydayadd-ACCESS.nc  I am very sorry to write the code in comment. It is the simple command that is working fine with two inputs. The corresponding file means there is a specfic file for each input in  f1 that has to be used with input in f2. I am trying to write the code in proper way in comments section

Comment: cdo ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-bcc.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-bcc.nc ydayadd-bcc.nc   and so on

Comment: @JahangirAli, if any of what you're posting in comments now is relevant to your question, please [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49703934/edit).

Comment: @ghoti Thank you I have edited the question

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have edited the question.

Comment: @userunknown I have edited the post. It will help explain the corresponding file

Answer (score 1):

A very different question now! And I've first overseen, that the dates don't match for zero- and avm-file.

You don't need 2 loops, but a mapping. `${f1/zero-mam-2050-2074-/}` extracts something like `-BNU.nc`, which needs to appended to the *tasmax* file and to your *ydayadd*-file too.

For testing, above code should work, if you gave us all neccessary information. For really performing the work, replace `echo` with `cdo`:

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074-*.nc
do
   ext=${f1/zero-mam-2050-2074-/}
   f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-${ext}
   cdo ydayadd "$f1" "$f2" ydayadd-$ext
done
```

(There was another error, in that I used `ext=${f/zer` instead of `ext=${f1/zer`.)

Test:

```
ls -1
avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS.nc
avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-bcc.nc
avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-BNU.nc
zero-mam-2050-2074-ACCESS.nc
zero-mam-2050-2074-bcc.nc
zero-mam-2050-2074-BNU.nc

alias cdo=echo 
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074-*.nc
> do
>    ext=${f1/zero-mam-2050-2074-/}
>    f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-${ext}
>    cdo ydayadd "$f1" "$f2" ydayadd-$ext
> done
ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-ACCESS.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS.nc ydayadd-ACCESS.nc
ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-BNU.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-BNU.nc ydayadd-BNU.nc
ydayadd zero-mam-2050-2074-bcc.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-bcc.nc ydayadd-bcc.nc
```

Comment: You don't need the `$(echo ...)`.  Just use: `ext="${f/zero-mam-2050-2074/}"`

Comment: Thanks, of course - mechanically taken from testing.

Comment: It gives open failed on avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACESS.nc avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-BNU.nc  so on.. The same explanation is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101220/for-loop-with-two-input-files?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes, I've overseen, that the dates DONT match between zero- and avm-file. For testing, above code should work, if you gave us all neccessary information. For really performing the work, replace `echo` with `cdo`.

Comment: I think I have to rename the files so that there is only a difference of single character.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following script will show you one way to get what you want. This script echos the filename that are 'matched' up - change that command to be whatever you really want.

Note: this script assumes that you want the filenames "paired" based on the substring that matches the wildcard `"*"` character.

It uses some bash variable replacement to strip off the parts of the filename in the first list of files that don't match the part of the name that matches the `"*"` wildcard (leaving the `$wildcard` variable with the substring that matched the `"*"`). It then uses that to construct the second filename in the pair.  There's probably a better way to this operation, but I'm not a shell or bash expert.

Hopefully if this doesn't quite do what you need, it'll give you some ideas:

```
for f1 in zero-mam-2050-2074*.nc
    do 

    # remove the part of the filename from before the "*" wildcard
    wildcard=${f1#zero-mam-2050-2074}

    #remove the part of the filename from after the "*" wildcard
    wildcard=${wildcard%.nc}

    # create the second filename
    f2=avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-${wildcard}.nc
    echo "$f1" "$f2"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this

Comment: It says open failed on avm-mam-1976-2000-tasmax-ACCESS.nc No such file or directory. It is not picking from f2. I will look into it

Comment: Note that my example doesn't check that `$f2` exists - it merely constructs the filename based on the the filename in `$f1`.  You need to specify what the script should do if `$f2` doesn't exist.